# Spark: RDD to Local Sparse Matrix

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am having an rdd of the format: `RDD[(Int, Int, Double)]`. Where the first value corresponts to the row index, the second one corresport to the column index and the third on is the value in this row index, column index.

How to create a local sparse matrix from this rdd? What I have done is the following:

```
val denseLocalMatrix = new CoordinateMatrix(inputRDD.map {
    case (row, col, rw) => MatrixEntry(row.toLong, col.toLong, rw)
  })
  .toBlockMatrix()
  .toLocalMatrix()
```

But this is a dense local matrix. How to make a sparse one from the initial `inputRDD`? Any insights?

I would expect `Matrices.sparse` format to be something similar to `csr_matrix((data, (row_ind, col_ind)), [shape=(M, N)])` of python `scipy` library, but that not the case as `Matrices.sparse` is expecting:

```
SparseMatrix(numRows: Int, numCols: Int, colPtrs: Array[Int], rowIndices: Array[Int], values: Array[Double])
```

colPtrs: the index corresponding to the start of a new column.

rowIndices: the row index of the entry. They must be in strictly increasing order for each column.

So I cant think of a way to use this one somehow straight ahead.

**Edit**:

Another way to define the question is:

How to `(colIndices:Array[Int], rowIndices: Array[Int]) => (colPtrs:Array[Int], rowIndices: Array[Int])`

Comment: Can't you use `denseMatrix.toSparse()`?

Comment: No its not possible. `value toSparse is not a member of org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Matrix`. Actually it seems that the output of `.toLocalMatrix()` is a `Matrix`..And even if it was possible it doesnt make sence from a coo matrix => dense matrix => sparse matrix. The dimension of the matrix is to big to be transformed to dense matrix.